# Create and assign values to a variable in a for loop with the same name of the list element

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

this is my first question in this page.

I have a list that helps me web-scraping through the elements of the list:

```
list = ["web-page","web-page1", "web-page2"]
```

Then there is the Web-Scrape Procces that iterates over the list of webpages to scrape.
I have code inside this procces, a little procces to clean the scrape for each web-page and concatenate this results for a final dataframe.

```
result = pd.concat([characteristic1, characteristic2], axis=1, sort=False)
result2 = pd.concat([result, characteristic3], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Now I want to create a final DataFrame that with the same name of the web-page it has scraped (e.g. "web-page")  but I just don't know how to do it.

```
df = pd.concat([result2, characteristic4], axis=1, sort=False)
```

This would give me only the results of the last web-page I've scraped because the for loop iterates and erases the "df" variable. How can I make a final dataframe for each web?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary to store your result.

```
result = {}

# In the loop   
result[pagename] = df
```

Or you can put them in a list

```
result = []

# In the loop
result.append(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think about it!
I used it and then concat it by itself to have a DataFrame